# How to get the path of an mp3 file from sd card on selecting the filename from playlist?

Tags: android, eclipse, media-player, sd-card, playlist

I am trying to make a media player in android which will play a song from sd card after selecting the song name from playlist. But for this I need to get the path of the selected file, which I want to pass to another activity using intent so that the song could be played on that activity. I have made a the playlist consisting the song names and on selecting a song from it currently what I am getting is the name of that file. I am unable to understand how to get the path of the desired file as the playlist consists files from multiple folders. Can anyone please help? I am just a beginner and still learning about android.

Here is my code I have written till now -

```
    public class playlist extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
    ListView list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;
    ArrayList<String> listTest;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    MediaController c;
    String p;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playlist);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        listTest = new ArrayList<String>( );

        Scanner("/sdcard/Music/");


        if(listTest.size() != 0)
        {
            listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (playlist.this,R.layout.simplerow, listTest);
            list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
            {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                //String p = list.getPath();
                String name = (String) ((TextView) view).getText();
                Toast.makeText(playlist.this,name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                /*Intent i = new Intent(playlist.this,MainActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("show", name);

                i.putExtras(b);
                playlist.this.startActivity(i);*/

            }
            });
          }
        }


        private void Scanner(String path) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            {
                try 
                {
                        File fl = new File(path);
                        File[] listOfFiles = fl.listFiles();              

                        for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles)
                         {
                            String s = listOfFile.getName();

                            if(s.endsWith(".mp3"))
                            {

                            //tv.setText( tv.getText()+"\n"+s);
                            listTest.add(s);
                            //p = (new File(URI.create(path))).getAbsolutePath();

                            }


                            /////////////////////////////////
                            File f = new File(path+s+"/");
                            if (f.exists() && f.isDirectory()) {
                            Scanner(path+s+"/");
                            }
                            /////////////////////////////////


                        }



                }
            catch (Exception e) { }
            }

            }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class to read the mp3 files from a directory and its path

```
public class Test
{
    private List<File> fileList;

    private class Mp3Filter implements FilenameFilter
    {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
        {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3"));
        }

    }
    /**
     * reads the file names and store in list
     * @param mainPath the path to look at, example /sdcard
     */
    public void getMp3Files(String mainPath)
    {
        File home = new File(mainPath);
        if (fileList == null)
            fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
        Mp3Filter mp3Filter = new Mp3Filter();
        if (home.listFiles(mp3Filter) != null && home.listFiles(mp3Filter).length > 0)
        {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(mp3Filter))
            {
                //this is the file path you want to pass to the player
                String filePath = file.getPath();
                fileList.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```